# Mongo Meteor AWS EC2 Multiple Deploy

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2

I was using Galaxy to host my meteor app and recently decided to host my app with Amazon Cloudfront serving static webpage (angular client) and connect that to my meteor app running on an EC2 container.

I have the static page working and I have the meteor app on the EC2 container, which points to a remote mongo server, working as well.  I am using the meteor-client-bundler package to attempt to connect the client (static cloudfront) to the Meteor server via DDP URL.  Here is where I am stuck.

The DDP Url should be my meteor server correct? Hosted at ec2....amazonaws.com)?  I feel like it has to be because I have publications and methods on the server I will need to hit constantly. If that is correct, then what if I also want to have two EC2 containers running the same Meteor app?  Just like in Galaxy, in case 1 is getting maintenance work done or goes down, I want the backup to take over.  How can I set up two different DDP urls?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom domain for the server, and use that custom domain in the DDP URL. While using the EC2 address will work, it's better to use a different address, especially if you ever want to move to another provider.

You can use NGINX as a reverse proxy to have 2 or more Meteor apps on the one box. It's not too difficult to set up.

You can also use Meteor up (aka mup) to do multiple deployments to the same box. http://meteor-up.com/ Meteor up will give you a very simple way to deploy, it will even revert to the previous version if something goes wrong automatically. You can even configure it to run letsencrypt to give you https security, and automatically renew the certs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is new to this stuff like I am, I figured out to buy another domain name, use dns (route 53) to a load balancer (elastic beanstalk) which handles multiple ec2s for 1 domain, and then point your ddp from the client to the domain. Boom. Thanks for the help @Mikkel